# Nginx and Noisy PHP Error Log

Tags: php, nginx

Whenever a PHP error occurs or the error_log() function is used in PHP on an Nginx/PHP-FPM server, the log entry is always in the format:

```
<TIMESTAMP> 506#0: *66699 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: <MESSAGE FROM PHP SCRIPT>" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: <SERVER>, request: "<HTTP CALL>", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "<HOST>", referrer: "<REFERRAL>"
```

Is there any way to make this cleaner so that there isn't so much excessive text like the way Apache logs errors? For example:

```
<TIMESTAMP>, <IP> <PHP MESSAGE>, <REFERRAL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late, but I had the same problem as you.
Unfortunately I haven't found any software or other solution to the problem.
So I sat down and wrote a program myself, which reformats the log.

https://github.com/marcelhencke/nglog

---

For your concrete case you would have to call the log as follows:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log | nglog -t "%ts%, %ng_client% %php%, %ng_referrer%"
```